# Lyapunov Function for Nonlinear System

Tags: stability-in-odes, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

Which Lyapunov function should I choose to show the stability (or instability) of equilibrium points? With $k>0$, $K>0$, $\delta >0$. The system is Hurwitz (asymptotically stable) when $k>K$. Standard quadratic Lyapunov function
\begin{equation}
    V(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = \frac{k(x_1-x_2)^2}{2}+\frac{x_3^2}{2}+\frac{x_4^2}{2}-\frac{K(x_1-x_2)^2}{2}
\end{equation}
does not work.
Linearized system
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\dot{x}_1=x_3,\\
\dot{x}_2=x_4,\\
\dot{x}_3=-k(x_1-x_2)-K x_2,\\
\dot{x}_4=k(x_1-x_2)-\delta x_4,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
gives
\begin{equation}
    A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0& 0& 1& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 1\\
-k& k-K& 0& 0\\
k& -k& 0& -\delta
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
By the Lyapunov's converse theorems I know that there exists a unique symmetric positive definite matrix $P$ as a solution to the Lyapunov equation with $\boldsymbol Q=\boldsymbol I$:
$$\boldsymbol{PA}+\boldsymbol{A^TP}=-\boldsymbol{Q}$$
I have tried to solve it symbolically via Matlab, but did cope with it. I have also tried to differentiate Lyapunov function without knowing explicit form for $\boldsymbol {P}$ but the result of $\boldsymbol {\dot{V}} = \boldsymbol x^T \boldsymbol P \boldsymbol x$ gives the system of 16 equations which I could not solve as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of MATHEMATICA.

$$
A = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 -k & -k-K & 0 & 0 \\
 k & -k & 0 & -\delta  \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and the command

```
P = LyapunovSolve[A, Transpose[A], -IdentityMatrix[4]]
```

we obtain

$$
P = \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 -\frac{\delta ^2 \left(3 k K+k (3 k+2)+K^2+K\right)+K (k+K) (2 k+K+1)}{2 \delta  k (k+K) (2 k+K)} & -\frac{\delta ^2 k+\delta ^2 K+K}{4 \delta  k^2+2
   \delta  k K} & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{k+1}{2 (k+K)} \\
 -\frac{\delta ^2 k+\delta ^2 K+K}{4 \delta  k^2+2 \delta  k K} & \frac{\delta ^2 (k+K)+K (2 k+K+1)}{2 \delta  (k+K) (2 k+K)} & \frac{k+1}{2 (k+K)} &
   -\frac{1}{2} \\
 -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{k+1}{2 (k+K)} & -\frac{\frac{\delta ^2 \left(2 k^2+2 k K+k+K^2\right)}{k+K}+(k+1) K}{2 \delta  k} & \frac{K}{2 \delta } \\
 -\frac{k+1}{2 (k+K)} & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{K}{2 \delta } & \frac{k K+K}{2 \delta  k+2 \delta  K} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$